# Why is isAnonymous returning false when using Kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I'm using MVVM architecture to check if a user is signed-in anonymous. In my repository class I have this this field:

```
val isUserAnonymous = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.isAnonymous
```

In the ViewModel class I have:

```
val isUserAnonymous = repository.isUserAnonymous
```

And in my activity I use something like this:

```
R.id.sign_out_button -> {
    if (mainViewModel.isUserAnonymous!!) {
        Log.d("TAG", "isUserAnonymous: " + isUserAnonymous) //False
    }
}
```

Right after I successfully sign-in and I press the sing-out button, the `isUserAnonymous` is evaluated to **false**. However, if I use:

```
R.id.sign_out_button -> {
    if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.isAnonymous) {
        Log.d("TAG", "isUserAnonymous: " + isUserAnonymous) //True
    }
}
```

`isAnonymous` is evaluated to **true**. Why? How can I get the value of true, when I use the code in my repository class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change `isUserAnonymous` implementation to this:

```
val isUserAnonymous: Boolean?
    get() = repository.isUserAnonymous // in view model
val isUserAnonymous: Boolean? 
    get() = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.isAnonymous // in repository
```

When you declare `get()` method for your variables instead of backing `field` value returned you are able to return value that is calculated at the moment of invocation of this variable.

It would be similar to writing two methods instead of variables:

```
// in view model
fun isUserAnonymous(): Boolean? { 
    return repository.isUserAnonymous
}

// in repository
fun isUserAnonymous(): Boolean? {
    return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.isAnonymous
}
```

Comment: Waw, it really worked man. Thank you so much for your quick response. Voted-up. I will accept your answer after 15minutes.